# Adding and sorting values in a Bash script

Tags: bash, sorting

I've been trying so solve this problem but none of the things I tried actually work. I have a table in which (from a .txt file) that I need to sort by numerical order of a specific raw of the table.

The data I have is composed like this:

```
Name  Team Age    
David  a   20   
James  b   25   
Anthony  c   22  
Carter  b   21   
Jessica  a   24
```

Basically what I need to order (from smallest to biggest) the age of a certain team, example A. So the expected output would be:

```
a 20    
a 24
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$2==team{print $2,$3}' team='a' file | sort -t' ' -k2n
```

Comment: if I wanted to sort the resulting data in reverse I should be able to do it adding -r to the sort command, right? because that bit doesn't work

Comment: @AndreaCRD it works with GNU sort, but yeah you can try specifying `-r` separately if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @oguzismail I tried adding -r but it doesn't reverse the order

Comment: Which sort are you using? What's the output of `sort --version`?

Comment: @oguzismail I'm using the version you posted, just adding the -r flag. Output is: 2.3-Apple (99)

Comment: @AndreaCRD If your sort doesn't support `-r`, you can pipe its output to `tac` as a workaround. But as far as I know `-r` is a part of POSIX sort for a long time if not from the beginning.

Comment: it works now, thanks! what if I wanted to sort rows that only have a specific attribute in one of their fields? @oguzismail

Comment: @AndreaCRD that's another question. Either ask another question, or edit this one to add this new requirement with example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this very easily with SQL and the SUM and GROUP BY functions:

```
SELECT team, SUM(age) FROM table1 GROUP BY team;

+------+----------+
| team | SUM(age) |
+------+----------+
| a    |       44 |
| b    |       46 |
| c    |       22 |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: How does this answer the OP (*i.e.* "in a Bash script")?

Answer (score 0):

Bash alone is clearly not the best tool for this job.

If you love Bash code like I do, you will probably still be interested in a Bash-only solution (well, almost, let's not reinvent the `sort`ing):

```
#!/bin/bash

firstline=true
declare -A sumPerTeam     # declare associative array

# collect sum for each team in the associative array:
while read name team age
do
    [ "$firstline" = true ] && { firstline= ; continue ; }    # skip header
    sumPerTeam[${team}]=$(( "${sumPerTeam[${team}]}" + age ))
done < input.txt

# output each key/value pair of the array:
for team in "${!sumPerTeam[@]}"
do
    echo "$team" "${sumPerTeam[${team}]}"
done | sort -k2
```

Associative arrays are not Bash's most readable feature.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` solution without a separate pipe and subshell to sort could be:

```
awk '$2 == "a" {arr[$3]} END {for (i in arr) print "a", i}' file
```

You simply store the `age` as indexes in an array and then output the indexes at the end which provides an inherent sort without a separate process, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '$2 == "a" {arr[$3]} END {for (i in arr) print "a", i}' file
a 20
a 24
```

Calling an external `sort`, you can reduce the number of characters you type, but then pickup the additional overhead of the pipe as well as the subshell required by `sort`, e.g.

```
awk '$2 == "a" {print $2, $3}' file | sort
```

(same output)

Comment: first solution you proposed will only work with GNU awk, other awks don't sort array indices before iteration.

Comment: and by calling sort without a key definition you're asking for an **alphabetically** sorted list of inputs, i.e `a 10` will come before `a 2`.